# Rapid Decomposition Of Fruits & Vegetables During Hurricane

Tags: mycology, vegetable, decomposition

A very strange thing (To my mind) has just happened in my home. On the eve of Hurricane Irma, I purchased some food including cucumbers and grapes. I left them in my kitchen area overnight. When I woke up the next day, the hurricane was overhead. I went into the kitchen and noticed a large puddle of water on the floor that smelled of cucumber. The bag I had left the cucumbers and grapes in was at the center of this puddle.

I opened the bag and saw that the cucumbers and some of the grapes had completely disintegrated. It wasn't as though they had decomposed in any normal way. There was no visible fungi and the cucumbers didn't look especially rotted, just mostly gone. Only a small portion of the cucumbers remained. Many of the grapes were in a similar state.

How is this possible? When I bought this produce, it was fresh, not old. They had been reduced to almost nothing in less than 24 hours. I tried researching possible causes for rapid decomposition but normal decomposition of a cucumber (To this point) takes several months. I wasn't able to find a single article or time-lapse that reflected my observation. I've always been very interested in mycology so I set out to find a fungus that might be responsible but I have as of yet been unsuccessful. Could the pressure of the atmosphere during the hurricane have played a role?

If anyone can explain this, I would love to know what happened. Do I have some rare fungi floating around my house? Should I be worried?

Comment: If possible, can you kindly include a picture of the grapes and cucumbers?